# FlashBuilder 4.5 :: Render Text without lifecycle for upsampling

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I need to find a way to "upsample" text from 72dpi (screen) to 300dpi (print) for rendered client generated text. This is a true WYSIWYG application and we're expecting a ton of traffic so client side rendering is a requirement. Our application has several fonts, font sizes, colors, alignments the user can modify in a textarea. The question is how to convert 72dpi to 300dpi. We have the editior complete, we just need to make 300dpi versions of the textarea.

### MY IDEA

1) Get textarea and increase the height, width, and font size by 300/72. (if ints are needed on font size I may need to increase the font then down-sample to the height/width)

2) use BitmapUtil.getSnapshot on the textarea to get a rendered version of the text

### THE QUESTION

How can I render text inside of a textarea without the component lifecycle? Imagine:

```
var textArea:TextArea = new TextArea();
textArea.text = "This is a test";    
var bmd:BitmapData = textArea.render();
```

Comment: Not my area of expertise; but I'm pretty sure changing the height / width will not do what you want to do.  Height and width have very little to do w/ DPI.  If you don't have 300DPI sources for what you're printing; I don't think you'll be able to print succesfully at 300DPI.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful reply. My question is not about the math of DPI but how to capture the BitmapData of a TextArea that is "offscreen". Being "offscreen" it should not be shown thus will not go through a component lifecycle like creationComplete. To ask a question another way, it is possible to create a TextArea in memory which I can use the BitmapUtil.getSnapshot() function to generate a BitmapData object.

Comment: Why wouldn't off screen elements go through their own component lifecycle?  If they were added to a container, they will renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final method I used to solve the problem of creating a printable version of the text and style of a Spark TextArea component. I ended up placing the custom component TextAreaRenderer (see below) in the MXML and setting the visibility to false. Then using the reference to this component to process any text field (renderObject) and get back a BitmapData object.

```
public class TextAreaRenderer extends TextArea implements IAssetRenderer
{

    public function render(renderObject:Object, dpi:int = 300):BitmapData{

        // CAST THE OBJECT
        //.................
        var userTextArea:TextArea = TextArea(renderObject);

        // SCALE IS THE DIVISION OF THE NEW DPI OVER THE SCREEN DPI 72
        //............................................................
        var scale:Number = dpi / 72;

        // COPY THE USER'S TEXT AREA INTO THE OFFSCREEN TEXT AREA
        //.......................................................
        this.text = userTextArea.text;                          // the actual text
        this.height = Math.floor(userTextArea.height * scale);  // scaled height
        this.width = Math.floor(userTextArea.width * scale);    // scaled width


        // GET THE LAYOUT FORMATS AND COPY TO OFFSCREEN
        // - the user's format =  userTextAreaLayoutFormat
        // - the hidden format = thisLayoutFormat
        //...............................................
        var editableLayoutProperties:Array = ['fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontWeight', 'fontStyle', 'textAlign', 'textDecoration', 'color']
        userTextArea.selectAll();
        var userTextAreaLayoutFormat:TextLayoutFormat = userTextArea.getFormatOfRange();
        this.selectAll();
        var thisLayoutFormat:TextLayoutFormat = this.getFormatOfRange();
        for each(var prop:String in editableLayoutProperties){
            thisLayoutFormat[prop] = userTextAreaLayoutFormat[prop];
        }

        // SCALE THE FONT SIZE
        //....................
        thisLayoutFormat.fontSize = thisLayoutFormat.fontSize * scale;

        // SET THE FORMAT BACK IN THE TEXT BOX
        //...................................
        this.setFormatOfRange(thisLayoutFormat);

        // REDRAW THE OFFSCREEN
        // RETURN THE BITMAP DATA
        //.......................
        this.validateNow();
        return BitmapUtil.getSnapshot(this);
    }
}
```

Then calling the TextAreaRenderer after the text area is changed to get a scaled up bitmap.

```
// COPY THE DATA INTO THE OFFSCREEN COMPONENT
//............................................
var renderableComponent:IAssetRenderer = view.offScreenTextArea;
return renderableComponent.render(userTextArea, 300);
```

*Thanks to the advice from www.Flextras.com for working through the issue with me.*

Answer (score 0):

Like Flextras said, width/height has nothing to do with DPI, unless you actually *zoom* into the application by 4.16X.  If your application all has vector based graphics, it shouldn't be a problem.  Plus, the concept of DPI is lost in any web application until you're trying to save/print a bitmap.

It's definitely possible, but you'll have to figure it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

> To ask a question another way, it is possible to create a TextArea in
>   memory which I can use the BitmapUtil.getSnapshot() function to
>   generate a BitmapData object

Technically, all components are in memory.  What you want to do, I believe, is render a component without adding it to a container.

We do exactly this for the watermark on Flextras components.  Conceptually we created a method to render the instance; like this:

```
public function render(argInheritingStyles : Object):void{
 this.createChildren();
 this.childrenCreated();
 this.initializationComplete();
 this.inheritingStyles = argInheritingStyles;
 this.commitProperties();
 this.measure(); 
 this.height = this.measuredHeight;
 this.width = this.measuredWidth;
 this.updateDisplayList(this.unscaledWidth,this.unscaledHeight);
}
```

The method must be explicitly called.  Then you can use the 'standard' procedure for turning the component into a bitmap.  I think we use a Label; but the same approach should work on any given component.

Comment: I tried this method and ran into several null object errors. I'm guessing the difference is you have an MX Label and I'm using a spark TextArea. This did give me the idea to try cloning the original spark TextArea but ran into a handful of other issues there. I ended up writing an extended class of TextArea with the render function and adding it to my MXML component with VISIBLE set to false (offscreen). Now I can pass the render component any TextArea with a DPI and get back BitmapData. I'll post the solution soon. Thanks for helping me work through the issue, your replies were big help.

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is w/o seeing more code.  Our initial implementation used an MX Label (back in the Flex 3 days). Our latest implementation uses a Spark Label and it works fine. However, a Spark TextArea extends SkinnableComponent ( which Label does not ).  It makes sense that the exact approach would need tweaking for a SkinnableComponent.  I suspect you may need a custom skin that goes through these steps in addition to the component class.  You may need to set the skinClass property before calling createChildren().  You'd have to look at SkinnabeComponent source to figure it out